# No SQL Query results after successful CSV import in mysql using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, load-data-infile

I am facing a strange problem after successfully importing the contents of a .csv file in mysql db. The data from the csv file is imported into the db table successfully but no query results are returned if i run any SQL query with a Condition on on the table. I am able to run the query :

```
select * from mst_question
```

but no results are returned if a condition is specified and the condition is met

```
select * from mst_question where qtype='single'
```

The table is having rows where the column qtype contains the condition text "single" but no results are returned.

**Strangely, if i edit the column "qtype" contents in the table and replace the test "single" by typing "single" the row is returned...** for every row i edit !!!

**My .csv file :**

```
que_id,test_id,que_desc,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans,qtype
,11,In which year is the HTML specification supposed to be complete and finalized?,2012,2015,2020,2022,D,single
,11,Which of the following doctypes was introduced by HTML5?,<!doctype xhtml>,<!doctype html>,"<!doctype html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 5.0 Transitional//EN"">","<!doctype html5 PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 5.0 Transitional//EN"">",B,single
,11,How do you stop crawlers from following links to sites you don't want to be associated with?,"<a href=""#"" rel=""nofollow""> ","<a href=""#"" rel=""dontgo""> ","<a href=""#"" rel=""nogo""> ","<a href=""#"" rel=""noassociation"">",A,single
,11,Which tag is used to define a section of the page that has content that is related but not critical to the main content in HTML5?,<article> ,<sidesection> ,<aside> ,<section> ,C,single
,11,The <article> is used to contain a main article. What is the tag used to break it into sections?,<article> ,<time> ,<aside> ,<section> ,D,single
```

**My LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE syntax :**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'quest.csv' INTO TABLE mst_question FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" IGNORE 1 LINES
```

**Output after the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is executed :**

```
(5 row(s)affected)
(0 ms taken)
```

**My SQL Query ( which gives results ) :**

```
select * from mst_question
```

*Result* :

```
(5 row(s)returned)
(0 ms taken)
```

**My SQL Query with simple condition ( which gives NO results ) :**

```
select * from mst_question where qtype='single'
```

*Result :*

```
(0 row(s)returned)
(0 ms taken)
```

What am i doing wrong ????

Cant find it.... Pls advise...

Comment: What are the results from 'select * from mst_question'. If we could see the data, that would make it easier.  I suspect there is some whitespace or hidden char (perhaps line returns) in the table after the import.

Comment: It looks like you may have some issues with how some of the csv strings are quoted.

Comment: Form what you're describing I'm essentially certain your db is storing a value subtly different from 'single' where you're looking for it. Could you run `select * from mst_question where qtype <> 'single';` and post the output?

Comment: @cms_mgr this returns all 5 rows !!

Comment: @Sandy505 so it should. Alvaro's answer below looks like a good explanation to me so try that out to see if it helps with your original query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your file has Windows line feeds:

```
...0,2022,D,single\r\n
```

You haven't specified the `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` clause so MySQL probably defaults to Unix style (`\n`) so it actually imports `single\r` into your column.

You can inspect exact column contents with `HEX()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to export the database as a sql file and look at its file contents.

Open the SQL file in a text editor, and look at the end of each inserted row. In last column you might see `\r`.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO `student` (`number`, `name`, `color`) VALUES
('1', 'David', 'Blue\r'),
('2', 'James', 'Yellow\r'),
```