# No results from mysql table populated by load data... from a csv file

Tags: mysql, csv

QUESTION: On a WINDOWS machine,  how do you write the  load data command. Where do I enter '\r\n'?

I loaded a csv file into a database table, see below

```
 mysql> load data local infile 'c:/STDDocJ.csv' into table 3rd_wave.productsbrand
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"';
```

I can see the data populated in the table in phpmyadmin. I could see the data,  no problem.
It looks good right?
[Screenshot how it looks in table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tk0q20fhihs1g2d/good.jpg)

**So I run a query:**

```
SELECT `products_status`FROM `productsbrand`
WHERE `products_status` = 'OOS'
```

which should return over 50 results but it comes back empty results.

If I manually add line items into the table, it works. 
So it must be a problem with the Load function. 
I found a partial solution here in StackOverflow but I don't see the exact syntax.
[Stackoverflow partial solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690823/no-sql-query-results-after-successful-csv-import-in-mysql-using-load-data-local)

I think it has to do with using a Window machine. See:

So I replaced FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' with:
              FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
And that put both piece of information in the same column.
See Here [Doubled Up](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9smnbls8t0n0u23/wrong.jpg)

It should be separate columns, like the spreadsheet.

SO the question remains, on a WINDOWS machine how do you write the  load data command. Where do I enter '\r\n'?

```
 mysql> load data local infile 'c:/STDDocJ.csv' into table 3rd_wave.productsbrand
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the "is it plugged in" question, but first make sure you're using the 3rd_wave database you inserted into before running your query against the table. ("use 3rd_wave" from mysql CLI)

The other thing that jumps out at me is that you're using LIKE in your query without any wildcards. If you want an exact match then this is already correct, otherwise check out this section of the query and change it to allow fuzzier string matching.

Comment: Thank you but there is no problem with the query. It works fine if the data was manually added. It is a problem with data populated with the Load command.  Thanks though. Karen